# Why does Dec memory address descend and Hex memory address ascend?

Tags: arrays, pointers, memory

I have written a C program to take input of 5 int/float/double values from the keyboard and store these in an array of the corresponding datatype.

The program writes a table to the screen, with the first column containing the memory addresses of the array elements in decimal, the second column containing the memory addresses of the array elements in hexadecimal and the third column containing the integer values held at the memory addresses.

On inspecting the table, I have noticed that int and float memory address value is decremented by 4 bytes and double by 8 whereas the Hexadecimal is incremented by 4 and 8 bytes.

Why does the Dec memory address descend and the Hex memory address ascend?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5

main()
{
    int i;
    int intArray[SIZE];
    float floatArray[SIZE];
    double doubleArray[SIZE];

    int* ptrIntArray;
    float* ptrFloatArray;
    double* ptrDoubleArray;

    ///assign pointers to arrays to point to the start of each array
    ptrIntArray=intArray;
    ptrFloatArray=floatArray;
    ptrDoubleArray=doubleArray;

    printf("enter %d integers: \n", SIZE);
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &intArray[i]);
    }
    printf("enter %d floats: \n", SIZE);
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        scanf("%f", &floatArray[i]);
    }
    printf("enter %d doubles: \n", SIZE);
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf", &doubleArray[i]);
    }

    printf("Memory address base 10\tMemory address base 16\tcontents at address\n");
    printf("Integers:\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t\t\t%x\t\t\t%d\n",ptrIntArray+i,ptrIntArray+i,*(ptrIntArray+i));
    }
    printf("\nFloats:\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t\t\t%x\t\t\t%f\n",ptrFloatArray+i,ptrFloatArray+i,*(ptrFloatArray+i));
    }
    printf("\nDoubles:\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t\t\t%x\t\t\t%lf\n",ptrDoubleArray+i,ptrDoubleArray+i,*(ptrDoubleArray+i));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
enter 5 integers: 
1
2
3
4
5
enter 5 floats: 
1.5
2.5
3.5
4.5
5.5
enter 5 doubles: 
1.55
2.55
3.55
4.55
5.55
Memory address base 10  Memory address base 16  contents at address
Integers:

-516081056          e13d3a60            1
-516081052          e13d3a64            2
-516081048          e13d3a68            3
-516081044          e13d3a6c            4
-516081040          e13d3a70            5

Floats:

-516081088          e13d3a40            1.500000
-516081084          e13d3a44            2.500000
-516081080          e13d3a48            3.500000
-516081076          e13d3a4c            4.500000
-516081072          e13d3a50            5.500000

Doubles:

-516081136          e13d3a10            1.550000
-516081128          e13d3a18            2.550000
-516081120          e13d3a20            3.550000
-516081112          e13d3a28            4.550000
-516081104          e13d3a30            5.550000

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 57.533 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-516081056          e13d3a60
-516081052          e13d3a64
-516081048          e13d3a68
-516081044          e13d3a6c
-516081040          e13d3a70
```

Both sets of numbers are increasing by `4` each iteration. The decimal numbers are negative is all. Use `%u` to print unsigned decimal numbers.